# unable to install requirements txt

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am getting below mentioned error when i am trying to install dependencies
,

> ./psycopg/psycopg.h:35:10: fatal error: libpq-fe.h: No such file or
> directory
> 35 | #include <libpq-fe.h>
>
> Depends: libpq5 (= 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1 is
> to be installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes from the fact that you do not have the `libpq-dev` package installed on your Ubuntu system.

You can solve this by either installing that package, or by using the `psycopg2-binary` package from pip instead of the `psycopg2` package. The `psycopg2-binary` package contains a pre-compiled binary which means that you don't have to build the C extension when installing the dependencies of your app.

So, plan of action:

Either, you make sure to install the dependent packages on Ubuntu according to the [psycopg2 documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/install/):

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
```

And then you should be able to run your requirements using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

The other option is to change the `psycopg2` line in your `requirements.txt` file so that it says `psycopg2-binary` instead, and then you shouldn't have to install the `libpq-dev` package.

You can read more about the differences between `psycopg2` and `psycopg2-binary` in their slightly longer [installation documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html)

Comment: on trying this command , it is showing this `Depends: libpq5 (= 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) but 14.1-2.pgdg20.04+1 is to be installed` and `psycopg2-binary` is already installed

Comment: thanks this line worked `The other option is to change the psycopg2 line in your requirements.txt file so that it says psycopg2-binary instead, and then you shouldn't have to install the libpq-dev package.`

Answer (score 0):

For specific version of python try

> sudo apt install python-dev libpq-dev

For example

> sudo apt install python3.9-dev libpq-dev

For python version 3.9

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).